# Why is (a=>1,b=>2){a} a syntax error?

Tags: perl

I want to use a hash in an expression. No problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %h = (a=>1, b=>2);
my $h = $h{a};
print "h='$h'\n";
```

But since I will refer to it only once, I don't want to name it. Naively substituting the hash content for $h doesn't work. The following code produces a syntax error on line 3 at "){":

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $x = (a=>1, b=>2){a};
print "x='$x'\n";
```

I know that the following is the way to accomplish what I need:

```
use struct;
use warnings;
my $y = {a=>1, b=>2}->{a};
print "y='$y'\n";
```

Why doesn't the second example work?

EDIT 1: This is a MVCE. In real life, my hash key ('a' in this example) is not a constant.

EDIT 2: A little more about my motive: I don't want an unnecessary variable in scope in my code, so if I were to restrict the scope of %h to where it really belongs, I would have this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $h;
{
    my %h = (a=>1, b=>2);
    $h = $h{a};
}
print "h='$h'\n";
```

I don't want to leave %h in scope for more code than I need, but it's also clunky to write the code segment with the extra block for scoping. This is why I was looking for a clean one-line way to make the assignment.

Comment: Because that's not a hash, it's a list with the following values: `'a', 1, 'b', 2`.

Comment: "But since I will refer to it only once, I don't want to name it." Why not just do `my $x = 1;`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'm assuming this is an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the contents of the hash (or the key being looked up) is not quite as simple or trivial as shown here.

Comment: @Dre That's exactly why I asked. This seems like an XY problem, but the example gives no hint of what the OP is actually trying to do. The only reason I can think to create a hashref and immediately throw it away is that it has side effects, e.g. one of the values is a tied object, but that would almost certainly be bad design. IMHO, a good answer to this question would explain that `my $y = {a=>1, b=>2}->{a};` is bad coding style and would address the OP's actual problem (assuming the OP explains it).

Comment: The real hash keys are 'darwin', "MSWIn32", and so on. The real {a} in the problem is actually $^O. So, the assignment is a one-time shot, depending on the OS it's running on.

Comment: @CaryMillsap I would edit that into your question, it's much more interesting than your current version (i.e. solutions are non-trivial). Personally, I would create the hash and do the lookup in two separate statements; `$^O` only has on the order of 25 distinct values, so you won't be saving much memory by doing it all in one shot and you're harming readability.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thank you for the feedback. I really did mean for the question to be "why is this syntax apparently non-compositional?" as opposed to "what is the best way to assign an OS-dependent value to a string variable?" I was stuck on the notion that (a=>1,b=>2) [which I did already know was equivalent to (a,1,b,2)] should be a perfectly  legitimate way to express a hash, when—out of context—it's not.

Comment: To make it compositional, create a hash reference and dereference it. `{a => 1, b => 2}->{a}` is one way. `${{a => 1, b => 2}}{b}` is another.

Comment: @mob: Indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, `(something1, something2, ...)` is not an array constructor. It's just a way to say to interpreter that "we have something in a list context". You can understand each `(a,b,c,...)` usage like an assignment to an array with no name. So, yes we can get a value from this array by index. `('a' => 1, 'b' => 2)[1]` will return `1`.

Hash will be created only after assignment in list context if left side is a hash variable. Before assignment we can't use this list like hash because we don't have hash. So postcircumfix operation `{...}` is not allowed.

Comment: `(foo, bar)` does not create list context: in `my $foo = ('foo', 'bar');`, both the LHS and RHS are evaluated in scalar context.

Comment: If you mean "does not create list context for the assigment operation" you are right. The assigment has a scalar context. We just use poped value from "array with no name" to assign `'bar'` to `$foo`

Comment: My point is that this: 'It's just a way to say to interpreter that "we have something in a list context"' is not correct. `(foo, bar)` does not indicate list context.

Answer (score 5):

In `my $x = (a=>1, b=>2){a};`, that doesn't represent a hash. It's a list with the following values: `'a', 1, 'b', 2`. The `=>`, aka fat-comma is simply a glorified comma, with the feature that it quotes the value on the left hand side. It does not implicitly mean that we're dealing with/creating a hash. Example:

```
my @array = ('a' => 1 => 'b' => 2);
```

To get the value `1` from the original code shown, you'd have to do `my $x = (a=>1, b=>2)[1];`.

The hashref method you used: `my $y = {a=>1, b=>2}->{a};` is the standard way to use an anonymous hash.

Comment: @MaxLybbert `(...)[1]` is a [list slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) and works just fine.

Comment: `perl -wMstrict -E 'my $x=(a=>1,b=>2)[1]; say $x'` ...prints `1`

Comment: I tested the wrong thing:  `perl -Mv5.16 -e 'say (1..10)[2]'` => `syntax error at -e line 1, near ")["`  But that's because Perl thinks I'm asking for the third element of the result of calling `say(1..10)`.  I withdraw the earlier criticism.

Comment: @MaxLybbert If you do that with warnings, you get `say (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.` --  Adding extraneous parenthesis, your code is being interpreted as `( say (1..10) )[2]`, if you do `perl -Mv5.16 -we 'say( (1..10)[2])'` it returns as expected

Comment: @MaxLybbert That's because `print`/`say` [interpret the parentheses as enclosing the arguments](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html): "Be careful not to follow the `print` keyword with a left parenthesis unless you want the corresponding right parenthesis to terminate the arguments to the print; put parentheses around all arguments (or interpose a `+`, but that doesn't look as good)."

Comment: @MaxLybbert... nope, add `-wMstrict` and you'll get more informative output: `say (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.`